# How can I target three IDs with the same function?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to apply the same function to three different IDs. I've created a fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/jnoweb/xrpsshcp/

```
var game = {score:0},
scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score1");

function add20() {
  TweenLite.to(game, 1, {
      score:"+=20", 
      roundProps:"score", 
      onUpdate:updateHandler, 
      ease:Linear.easeNone
  });
}

function updateHandler() {
  scoreDisplay.innerHTML = game.score;
}

add20();
```

So I'm trying to animate the black numbers in the same way as the red number. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Make an `Array` of elements, store it in `scoreDisplay` like you did with the first element.

```
scoreDisplay = [
  document.getElementById("score1"),
  document.getElementById("score2"),
  document.getElementById("score3")
];
```

**Step 2**: perform your update function for each element, by using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
function updateHandler() {
   scoreDisplay.forEach(function(display) {
     display.innerHTML = game.score;
   });
}
```

In your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ku72qy7e/